# QFT Inner Product Positive Definiteness

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-electrodynamics

When constructing the QFT of the electromagnetic field, we could construct the Hilbert space through two different routes:

**Construction (1)**

We could take as a Hilbert space basis the set of states of definite field configuration such that
$$\hat{A^{\mu}}(\vec{x})\left|A^{\mu}\right>=A^{\mu}(\vec{x})\left|A^{\mu}\right>$$
We formally define the inner product between such states as
$$\left<A'^{\mu}|A^{\mu}\right>=\prod_{x\in\mathbb{R}^3}\delta(A'^{\mu}(\vec{x})-A^{\mu}(\vec{x}))$$
noting **positive definiteness** $$\left<A'^{\mu}|A^{\mu}\right> \geq 0$$
Any element of the Hilbert space is to be expressed as a superposition of such states, and thus the norm of any state should be positive definite. For example, any single particle state should have positive definite norm.

**Construction (2)**

Going through the usual mode expansions,
$$\hat{A^{\mu}}(x)=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32E(\vec{p})}\sum_{\alpha=0}^{3}\epsilon^{\mu}_{(\alpha)}(\vec{p})(\hat{a}_{(\alpha)}(\vec{p})e^{-ip\cdot x}+{\hat{a}_{(\alpha)}(\vec{p})^{\dagger}}e^{ip\cdot x})$$
$$\hat{\pi_{\mu}}(x)=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32E(\vec{p})}\sum_{\alpha=0}^{3}{\bigg(\frac{-i}{2}\bigg){\epsilon_{(\alpha)}}_{\mu}}(\vec{p})(\hat{a}_{(\alpha)}(\vec{p})e^{-ip\cdot x}-{\hat{a}_{(\alpha)}(\vec{p})^{\dagger}}e^{ip\cdot x})$$
imposing the comutation relations $$[\hat{A}^{\mu}(\vec{x}),\hat{\pi}_{\nu}(\vec{y})]=\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$$
we obtain
$$[\hat{a}_{(\alpha)}(\vec{p}), \hat{a}_{(\beta)}(\vec{q})^{\dagger}]=-\eta_{\alpha\beta}(2\pi)^3 2E(\vec{p})\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})$$
Assuming the existence of a vacuum state (we could prove that this is the case) $\left| 0 \right>$ such that $\hat{a}_{(\alpha)}(\vec{p})\left| 0 \right>$, we construct the usual Fock basis as
$$\left| (\vec{p}_1,\alpha_1), (\vec{p}_2,\alpha_2), ... \right> = \hat{a}_{\alpha_1}(\vec{p}_1)^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{\alpha_2}(\vec{p}_2)^{\dagger}...\left| 0 \right>$$
Consider the norm of a single particle state $\left|\vec{p}, \alpha\right> = \hat{a}_{\alpha}(\vec{p})\left | 0 \right>$
$$\left<\vec{p},\alpha|\vec{p}, \alpha\right> = - \eta_{\alpha\alpha}(2\pi)^3 E(\vec{p})\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{p})$$
For the scalar mode $\alpha = 0$, we find $\left<\vec{p},\alpha|\vec{p}, \alpha\right> < 0$, in contradiction with the Hilbert space construction above.

At the set theoretic level, the two Hilbert spaces are identical, however the choice of inner product we equip in each construction seems to be different. As a side remark, in case (2), the choice of inner product we endow the Hilbert space with is only *implicit*, and not constructed explicitly.

My question is, what is the concrete construction of inner product of case 2 in terms of the gauge field basis $\left | A^{\mu}\right>$ and why is there a contradiction in the first place? What goes wrong in (2) at the level of the operator algebra or set theoretic level? Please excuse my confusion...

Comment: Yes, for any _physical_ state, you should get the positive inner product. But you are confused with both the things. In the first case, the implicit assumption is $|A_{\mu}\rangle$ is a physical state which should obey the _Gupta Bleuler condition_  which short of excludes the possibility of including other two types of polarizations. In the second case, consider the particle physics metric $diag(1,-1^{i})$, you will get negative norm for lightlike polarization, So, consider i=1,2. You will get positive norm.

Comment: My question is not about the imposition of the gauge constraints, nor about the restriction to physical states.

Comment: Basically, you have a choice between Lorentz invariance or positivity of the inner product.  You can choose a noncovariant gauge, in which the timelike and longitudinal modes of the electromagnetic field are nondynamical, and all the $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ operators for the actually dynamical modes yield states with positive norm.  Or you can use a covariant gauge, but at the cost of the states created by $A_{0}$ having negative norm; this case is frequently nicer mathematically, but you have to show that the negative norm states are never produced in physical processes, which saves unitarity.

Comment: One thing to note about your construction (1), is that it is not consistent with the usual canonical commutation relations you would impose. (Which you essentially proved yourself by carrying out the steps in construction (2)).